# Is there an "Intangibility Charm" in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

Intangibility means the ability to pass through objects normally if they weren't there (i.e. walls, the ground, buildings)?

Does such a charm or spell exist in the Potterverse?

Comment: Does [teleportation](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Apparition) count?

Comment: Or is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UX2uqINTZco&feature=youtu.be&t=1m45s) more what you're after

Comment: There is, but it [doesn't always work](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/1/18/Tumblr_n2nhei5qmj1qew2ypo2_250.gif/revision/latest?cb=20140622045312)

Comment: There must be--it's used in the trick stairs at Hogwarts.

Comment: what trick stairs @CHEESE

Comment: @KyleV - http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Staircase

Comment: As Valorum alluded to, Platform 9 3/4 at Kings Cross Station has some sort of "intangibility charm" associated with it. Don't know how it's done though, hence the comment and not an answer.

Comment: @CHEESE That could just be a defective magic brick that Filch hasn't got round to fixing yet (or which is beyond his capabilities).

Comment: I'm also going to throw in the Death Veil, but I'm pretty sure that wasn't created by an Intangibility Charm...

Answer (score 4):

## There is, but we don't know anything about it.

The wall at Platform 9 3/4 can be passed through:

> "Not to worry," she said. "All you have to do is walk straight at the barrier between platforms nine and ten. Don't stop and don't be scared you'll crash into it, that's very important. Best do it at a bit of a run if you're nervous. Go on, go now before Ron."
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*, chapter 6</sub>

You could say that the barrier actually doesn't exist, and that's an illusion, but I think what happened in the second book disproves that:

> Both of them bent low over the handles of their trolleys and walked purposefully toward the barrier, gathering speed. A few feet away from it, they broke into a run and -
> CRASH.
> Both trolleys hit the barrier and bounced backward;
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, chapter 5</sub>

However, we don't know anything about the spell other than that it exists.

Comment: You might also want to mention the trick stairs in the Hogwarts staircases.

Comment: I always thought of those more as an illusion than anything real.

Comment: Is there any reason to assume that the same spell isn't cast on them as found at the gateway to Platform 9 ¾?

Comment: Because we don't see them in their solid state at any time. Someone steps through them and gets stuck, like stepping into a hole. That's how I understand it, at least.

Comment: So, precisely the same visual effect as the barrier. It looks real but you can cross through it as if it's not there. Hmm. Sounds like the same spell to me...

Comment: The difference is that we know that the barrier is real. We see it in its solid state. We don't with the stairs.