# Is there an X-Men character who represents Immovable Object?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Valorum's comment on [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154312/is-there-an-intangibility-charm-in-harry-potter) - and the link to the X-Men clip with Juggernaut - got me wondering.

In X-Men, Juggernaut represents an Unstoppable Force.  Once he starts running, nothing can stop him.

Is there a mutant (from the comics or the films) that represents an Immovable Object?

If so, have they ever fought?

Comment: Mjolnir is an immovable object, though not an X-Men character.

Comment: @Adamant I have visions of Juggs running running grabs Mjolnir and tears his own arm off.  That'd be funny.

Comment: As a sidenote, an Unstoppable Force and an Immovable Object are the [same thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eKc5kgPVrA)

Comment: What about Colossus?

Comment: @Cristol.GdM - the paradox always assumes they are two separate things.  Otherwise there wouldn't be a paradox.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Blob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_(comics)) claims to be immovable as long as he's touching the ground.

He's fought the Hulk and Juggernaut before. Both were able to move him (eventually) but not without considerable effort.

**Hulk vs. Blob**
[image: Hulk vs. Blob]

**Blob vs. Juggernaut**
[image: Blob vs. Juggernaut]

**Juggernaut vs. Hulk**
[image: Juggernaut vs. Hulk]

Obviously in the current timeline, Blob is powerless and Juggernaut is hyper-powered so he's unlikely to be much of a threat at present.

Comment: I did note the Blob, but he seems less an immovable object than someone who can absorb/repel kinetic energy.

Comment: In the second strip I don't think that's Blob. Isn't that the Hulk as War?

Comment: @DCShannon - Sorry, yes. The perils of writing an answer past midnight :-)

Comment: Well, it's not just mislabeled. In the text you say that Blob has fought the Hulk and Juggernaut. *Has* he fought Juggernaut? If not, that strip isn't really relevant.

Comment: @DCShannon - He's fought both of them (see edit). And given that A>B>C, we can determine that Blob is less immovable than Hulk and that Juggernaut is capable of moving pretty much anything that isn't the Hulk, including the so-called immovable Blob.

Comment: That's better. Taken all together, it looks like a "no". Blob is the closest, but he's somewhat movable. Of course, War shows that Juggernaut isn't completely unstoppable, either.

Comment: @Tim What other kind of thing would be "immovable"? I can think of no better definition of "immovable" than "transferring energy to you has no effect on your position or velocity."

Comment: @jpmc26 Kitty Pryde?  She can't be moved if everyone goes right through her...

Comment: You'd have to have some kind of character like Wolverine, but whose skeleton was coated in Vibranium instead of Adamantium.

Comment: Also, http://marvelheroes.info/achievement/591/